# How to log pid(process id) by using spdlog

Tags: pid, spdlog

`spdlog` can log `threadid` by doing:

`spdlog::set_pattern("*** [%H:%M:%S %z] [thread %t] %v ***");`

But how can I log the `pid(process id)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is already supported in latest versions, using the %P flag.